# Autocomplete API for google custom search

Tags: autocomplete, google-search-api, google-custom-search

I am trying to add autocomplete to a google custom search that that I have recently installed.

I managed to get the search to work by sending a request to googleapis.com/customsearch/v1 but now I am having trouble getting the autocomplete to work against the google custom search. I did enabled autocompletion on my custom search account, but I cannot find any APIs or ways for me to get a list of suggested words.

Is there any available API for autocomplete to suggest words within the custom search?

I did find this post, [Google Custom Search API Autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232367/google-custom-search-api-autocomplete), but I was unable to get it to work. Just wondering if there are any other suggestions or solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a long since abandoned question, but for anyone that is looking for this information, [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8415960/1332402) shows that it isn't available.  In addition, [here's Google's blog post](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ca/2015/07/update-on-autocomplete-api.html) about removing the autocomplete API (from public, non-search use).

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the terms up in your CSE account in Google. So login to Google, go to Products - Custom Search Engines - Autocompletions. I, however, have had mine working in the past but it doesn't appear to be working now. A google search indicates others are having same issue of it not currently working ..just FYI based on quick attempt to correct my problem.

Comment: I glossed over the API part .. whoops!